# SharePoint Online - Using [Me] filter for Multi line text column doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, people-picker, multiline-text-field, sharepoint-list-filter

I am on SP Online environment. I have a list with multiple columns. One of the column multi line text column (Approvers) has multiple users of below format. 
Approvers: User1; User2; User3; User4; User5..... using UserProfile Name.

[image]

I am trying to create Approver's view. If a user that belongs to Approver's column accesses this view, he should be able to see that item. I added filter to achieve this, Approver contains [Me], which doesn't seem to work.

After digging deep, i learnt that [Me] can only be applied to a User or group column(People Picker).

Any other ideas to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the column multi line text

Change this to a People/Group column that allows multi-select ("Allow multiple selections") and then filter for [Me].  [Me] must be a real user, and multi-line text columns are just text, not users.

If you want a short list of users to select from (not all users), create a SharePoint group ("Choose from") with just those users and limit the People/Group column to that group.

---

You could also create People columns, one for each possible approver, and use a workflow to split the names across these columns. You can hide these columns in the view and still use them to filter. Create a series of "OR" filters, one for each column, that each filters on [Me].

Comment: I guess, First approach is good if he is not storing anything else besides names of the approvers. But, in second case it will not be feasible to create the person or group columns if number of approvers are going to change everytime.

Comment: Seems like you cannot use Approvers(Multi people column) contains [Me] filter. Contains is just for Single line or Multiline Text column

Comment: Seems like you have to use "Equal to" instead of contains. This works.

Answer (score 2):

[Me] only works for People column. The easiest way for your requirement is using Multi-people & group column to store the approvers instead of multi-line text column, then create a view and use [Me] to filter items.

Comment: Seems like you cannot use Approvers(Multi people column) contains [Me] filter. Contains is just for Single line or Multiline Text column

Comment: Seems like you have to use "Equal to" instead of contains. This works.

Comment: yes, you need to set the filter like "Approvers" "is equal to" "[Me]".